# Не заполняются поля формы полученными данными с ajax-запроса, как это побороть?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть форма:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
    <title>FE-Course. Part 3 | Registration form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Registration form</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="container">
        <form name="registration" class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator">
            <div class="form-group required">
                <legend class="col-sm-12">Registration info</legend>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="Login" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" placeholder="Email" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email2" placeholder="Confirm Email" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Address</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="ZIP Code">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state">
                          <option value="_none">Select State</option>
                          <option value="value1">State 1</option> 
                          <option value="value2">State 2</option>
                          <option value="value3">State 3</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="street" placeholder="Street">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="building" placeholder="Building">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Your Hobbies</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="checkbox col-sm-3">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox"> Music
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox col-sm-3">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox"> Cycling
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox col-sm-3">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox"> Front End
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox col-sm-3">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox"> Girls
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <legend>How did you hear about us?</legend>
                    <select class="form-control" id="about">
                      <option value="_none">Select Please</option>
                      <option value="value1">Google</option> 
                      <option value="value2">Friends</option>
                      <option value="value3">Newspapers</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg center-block" type="submit">Register Profile</button>
        </form>
    </section>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

с помощью ajax-запроса получаем данные с сервера:

```
    $.ajax({
url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#name').val(data.id);
    $('#login').val(data.id);
    $('#email1').val(data.id);
    $('#email2').val(data.id);
    }
  });
```

И необходимо динамически отобрать те, ключи которые совпадают с полями формы и заполнить ими форму. В ручную я пробовал это прописать, но как правильно это сделать автоматически(тот код что я написал не работает почему-то). Чтобы при каждом новом обращению к серверу, данные заносились в нужные поля. Посоветуйте кто знает.

Comment: Покажите ваши наработки по данному вопросу.

Comment: наработки, это когда уже понимаешь что делать, я пока что попробовал получить данные с сервера, это удалось, но как использовать эти данные в своей форме, я пока не знаю. Правильнее как их вытащить оттуда. Подскажите если можете. Спасибо.

Comment: Раз данные у вас приходят в формате json, то вероятно их следует превратить в JavaScript-объект/массив/значение функцией JSON.parse(data).

Comment: где об этом подробно почитать или посмотреть?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/json

Comment: unction populate(frm, data) {
 $.each(data, function(key, value){
  $('[name='+key+']', frm).val(value);
 });
}

var data = '{"name":"susanna fleming","login":"greenbutterfly745", "email":"susanna.fleming@example.com", "confirm email":"susanna.fleming@example.com"}';

populate('form', $.parseJSON(data)); вот что-то такое нарыл/написал, данные добавились в форму, но только первых два, почему-то. И как их автоматически достать с ответа сервера?

Comment: У вас поля email1 и email2, а json ответе приходят данные email и confirm email.

Comment: И может лучше вместо $('[name='+key+']', frm).val(value); делать так $('#'+key, frm).val(value); Менее затратно должно быть.

Comment: спасибо за подсказку, вижу уже, то есть этих данных я могу прописать столько, сколько у меня полей. А как можно сделать чтобы это происходило автоматически?

Comment: Что именно автоматически? Данные из ajax запроса, чтобы автоматически в форму прописывались? Так для этого у вас в запросе и прописывается функция success: function(data){...}

Comment: да что бы данные из запроса в форму попадали, но функция неправильно у меня работает ибо данные не записываются.

Comment: Открывайте консоль браузера и смотрите в ней ошибки js если есть. так же можете в браузере запустить отладчик кода и пошагово выполнять скрипт.

Comment: в том то и дело что в консоли нет ошибок...

Comment: В отладчике делайте пошаговое выполнение скрипта и ищите в чем проблема.

Comment: мне кажется что ошибка в том, что я не написал функцию для автоматического заполнения данных с запроса в форму.. у меня вот такая запись только: success: function (data, textStatus) {
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        console.log(data);
    });

Comment: Вы выше показывали функцию populate(). Так вызовите ее в success или ее функционал пропишите внутри success.

Comment: Вот такую сделал запись, но пишет populate is not defined  $.ajax({
 url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
 dataType : "json",
 success: function (data, textStatus) {
  function populate(frm, data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, value){
    $('#'+key, frm).val(value);
   });
  }
  console.log(data);
 }
});
populate('form', $.parseJSON(data));

Answer (score 1):

Нужно проверить в каком виде приходят данные с сервера. По хорошему они должны приходить в json формате тогда перед тем как использовать их в качестве значений, нужно распарсить json. JSON.parse(data)

Comment: $.parseJSON делать не нужно, т.к. данные сразу приходят с заголовком "json"

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот так все отлично работает:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var props = {};

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        var user = data.results[0].user,
            list = $('.form-control');

        deepSearch(user);

        for (var i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; i += 1) {
            prop = props[ $(list[i]).attr('id') ];
            if ( prop ) $(list[i]).val(prop);
        }

    }
});

function deepSearch(node) {
    for (var elem in node) {
        if ( isObjectEmpty(node[elem]) ) {
            props[elem] = node[elem];
        } else {
            deepSearch(node[elem]);
        }
    }
}

function isObjectEmpty(obj) {
    if (typeof obj !== 'object') return true;
    for (var key in obj) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
});
```